# Hacer replace cuando tengo #{

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

Nesesito hacer un replace de un texto pero no realiza nada la variable `one` tiene como comienzo `#{`

```
var one='#{listaFestividad.obtenerLista("December 22")}';
var fecha='May 03';
var res =one.replace('December 22', fecha);
```

Al momento de imprimir con `innerHTML` se me obtiene lo mismo sin modificarse
`document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=res;`

Respuesta
`#{listaFestividad.obtenerLista("December 22")}'`
siendo esto incorecto sabe alguien como mandar creo que el problema es por `'#{'` al comienzo del texto. sabe como mandar esto de alguna otra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Ya probe el codigo y el #{ no deberia afectar al replace que utilizas de hecho se remplaza correctamente el December 22 por el May 03

```js
var one='#{listaFestividad.obtenerLista("December 22")}';
var fecha='May 03';
//obtencion de texto incluyendo comillas
var res =one.replace('"December 22"', fecha);
document.write(res);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>prueba replace js</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: incluyendo las comillas en tu codigo, realice la edicion.